# Scala type members variance

Tags: scala, variance, higher-kinded-types

Consider this short snippet:

```
trait Table[+A] {
  type RowType = Seq[A]
}
```

Scala 2.11.7 compiler gives the following error:

```
covariant type A occurs in invariant position in type Seq[A] of type RowType
```

Why is `A` considered to be in invariant position in `Seq[A]` while `Seq` itself is defined as `trait Seq[+A]`?

Also, could you please provide a use case demonstrating possible issues with this type definition if we ignore the error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any `B <: A` your `Table[B]#RowType` will be more concrete than `Table[A]#RowType`. More concrete does not mean the same, so compiler is considering parameters for type aliases as invariant positions.

How you could fix this.

#### Abstract member

You can define your type as abstract, that mean you should define it later and probably stuck with same problem, but on `trait Table` level such definition will be correct

```
trait Table[+A] {
  type RowType <: Seq[A]
}
```

#### Concrete higher-kinded type

You can define parameterized type member, which could lead to changing how you can use this type, but in most cases should do the job.

```
trait Table[+A] {
  type RowType[+X] = Seq[X]
}
```

### On type member variance

Not the strongest my field but i try to describe my thoughts.

Suppose you have

```
trait Table[+A] {
  type RowType = Seq[A]
}

def mkTable[A]: Table[A]  = new Table[A] {}
```

then you do following

```
val tupleTable = mkTable[(String, String)]
val prodTable: Table[Product] = tupleTable
```

So what would be `prodTable.RowType`?

In case of your definition it should be `Seq[Product]`. But wait, `prodTable` and `tupleTable` are the same object, so their members should be the same, so `prodTable.RowType` should be `Seq[(String, String)]`

But if you change to the first approach like

```
trait Table[+A] {
  type RowType <: Seq[A]
}

def mkTable[A]: Table[A]  = new Table[A] {
  type RowType = Seq[A]
}
```

Compiler would know that `RowType` for `Table[Product]` is some type `<: Seq[Product]` which is true for `Seq[(String, String)]` and all ambiguilties are gone.

Comment: But why `A` is considered invariant? Does that mean that for `B <: A` sometimes `Table[B]#RowType <: Table[A]#RowType` wouldn't hold?

Comment: @FrozenSpider I tried to cover it my answer, but I'm not really good at it.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a counter-example:

```scala
import scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance

class Foo[+S](x: S) {
  type Shape = S @uncheckedVariance // THIS IS BAD
}
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fs: Foo[String] = new Foo("")
    
    def cast(x: Foo[Any]): x.Shape = 1 // This typechecks since x.Shape =:= Any
    
    val s: String = cast(fs) // This typechecks because Foo[String] <: Foo[Any], but results in a ClassCastException
    
  }
}
```

which throws:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Test$.main(main.scala:12)
```

Scastie link: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/smarter/Cno5sLZyTSybDC80uDt2hQ. Credit to @smarter.