# Covariant type parameter mentioned as a parameter in type member

Tags: scala, generics

```
trait Element[+A] {
  type T = A
}
// Error: covariant type A occurs in invariant 
// position in type A of type T type T = A
```

Why it's not allowed to use covariant type parameter in type member?

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458782/scala-type-members-variance) for this question, but the explanation doesn't cover question "why" enough good. Would be nice to have some examples where it break type system in runtime.

**Edit:**

As I found there is a long history of this restriction:

[SI-6566](https://github.com/scala/scala-dist/pull/131) (and [this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6566)) - non-private type aliases must be invariant

[SI-7093](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6566) - the protected[this] variance escape hatch is unsound

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523199/variance-annotations-in-type-aliases

Comment: Seems like the only way to go is `type T[A] = Seq[A]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala type members variance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458782/scala-type-members-variance)